# Fluent Validation C# Unique Id in collection

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have an entity that has a nested collection as a property which I will receive from a front-end application.

I just want to make sure that each item in this collection(ICollection ChildClassCollection) has a unique Id within the model I have received.

I am using FluentValidation and would like to add this validation using it too for consistency.

It's something very simple I couldn`t find an elegant way to solve..

An example:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildClass> ChildClassCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This question needs details or clarity

Comment: @Sergey I updated the description.

Comment: I added dbcontext code too.

Comment: @Sergey I don`t need that. These models as described are DTOs, I want to make back-end validation after data is received from the front end, this has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:
PRetty cleand, plus, when it encounters issue, it will exit

```
           this.RuleFor(or => or.ChildClassCollection)
               .Must(this.IsDistinct)
               .WithMessage("There are more than one entity with the same Id");

        public bool IsDistinct(List<UpdateRoleDTO> elements)
        {
            var encounteredIds = new HashSet<int>();

            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                if (!encounteredIds.Contains(element.Id))
                {
                   encounteredIds.Add(element.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HashSet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HashSet<ChildClass> ChildClassCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to make sure that only the Ids are unique, not the entire entity.

Comment: pls lokk this. https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/08/30/using-the-hashset-of-t-object-in-c-net-to-store-unique-elements-2/

Answer (score 1):

I use mine custom helper, based by ansver: [Check a property is unique in list in FluentValidation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019107/6384980). Because the helper is much more convenient to use than each time to describe the rules. Such a helper can be easily chained with other validators like `IsEmpty`.

**Code:**

```
public static class FluentValidationHelper
{
    public static IRuleBuilder<T, IEnumerable<TSource>> Unique<T, TSource, TResult>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, IEnumerable<TSource>> ruleBuilder,
        Func<TSource, TResult> selector, string? message = null)
    {
        if (selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector), "Cannot pass a null selector.");

        ruleBuilder
            .Must(x =>
            {
                var array = x.Select(selector).ToArray();
                return array.Count() == array.Distinct().Count();
            })
            .WithMessage(message ?? "Elements are not unique.");
        return ruleBuilder;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

For example we want to choose unique *id*

```
RuleFor(_ => _.ChildClassCollection!)
    .Unique(_ => _.Id);
```

Or want choose unique *id* and *name*

```
RuleFor(_ => _.ChildClassCollection!)
    .Unique(_ => new { _.Id, _.Name });
```

### Update

I optimization performance using code from answer [YoannaKostova](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67124276/6384980)

```
public static class FluentValidationHelper
{
    
    public static bool IsDistinct<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> elements, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<TResult>();
        foreach (var element in elements.Select(selector))
        {
            if (!hashSet.Contains(element))
                hashSet.Add(element);
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static IRuleBuilder<T, IEnumerable<TSource>> Unique<T, TSource, TResult>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, IEnumerable<TSource>> ruleBuilder,
        Func<TSource, TResult> selector, string? message = null)
    {
        if (selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector), "Cannot pass a null selector.");

        ruleBuilder
            .Must(x => x.IsDistinct(selector))
            .WithMessage(message ?? "Elements are not unique.");
        return ruleBuilder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use only fluentValidator to achieve this **without any relationship**?

If so, you can custom a validator,then use some logic to confirm whether there is a duplicate value

in database,like this:

```
public class ChildClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildClass>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public ChildClassValidator(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("ID is required.").Must(IsUnique).WithMessage("parent have more than one ids");
    }

    private bool IsUnique(int id)
    {
        var model = _context.ParentClasses.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
           .Select(y => y.Key)
           .ToList();  //judge whether parentclass has duplicate id
        if (model==null) 
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a bad idea. Validators - 98% of the time - are supposed to execute in-Memory validations on the data of the incoming object. Reaching out to the database from the validation layer should not be suggested unless there is an explicit request to do so. Database checks fit better to the handlers/managers/use cases of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using fluent validation like this below. This way you wouldn't iterate the same collection for every child item.

```
public class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentClass>
{
  public ParentValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(x => x.ChildClassCollection)
      .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
      .NotNull()
      .NotEmpty()
      .Must(x => x.Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().Count() == x.Count());
  }
}
```